# On system update: "python-gast03 and python-gast are in conflict"

Tags: arch-linux, python, upgrade, artix-linux

Trying to make a system update to upgrade Tensorflow:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

I am asked:

> :: python-gast03 and python-gast are in conflict. Remove python-gast? [y/N]

I say No:

> error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
> error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
> :: python-gast03 and python-gast are in conflict

I then try to remove the oldest of the packages:

```
sudo pacman -R python-gast03
```

and I get:

> error: target not found: python-gast03

So, where does this conflict come from if the oldest package is not even present?

Comment: it's asking if you want to remove `python-gast`, which means _that's_ the one installed, and `python-gast03` is the one it's trying to install

Comment: OK. Since the one I am asked to remove is the most recent version, possibly needed somewhere else, can I install both? Is there an option for that which does not cause any issues down the road?

Comment: given that they are configured as "conflicts", no, you can't install both

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue when updating my system.

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

I tried removing python-gast.

```
sudo pacman -R python-gast
```

I was told that python-tensorflow-opt-cuda was dependent on that package.
So, I updated it.

```
sudo pacman -S python-tensorflow-opt-cuda
```

It replaced gast with gast03 at that point.
Then, I could do a system update.

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

Everything worked as expected after that.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was running

> sudo pacman -R python-gast

and then updating whatever the dependency was.

In my case the command was

> sudo pacman -S python-tensorflow

This will tell you that there is conflicts and give you an option to remove the outdated one.

and then you can run the update just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am on BlackArch.
I faced same issue, then I uninstalled python-gast and other dependencies along with it.
And then, I upgraded system and then reinstalled it.
**Have a try?**

Answer (score 1):

Someone already made a bugreport for pacman:

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64785

Steps to solve the problem can be found in the report:

pacman -Sy python-tensorflow

pacman -Syu

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because tensorflow was built on python-gast 0.3.x version. now python-gast updated to 0.4 version, but the new version of tensorflow still based on 0.3.x which was rename to gast03.
So remove "python-gast(which will update to 0.4 version)" and update tensorflow(which will install python-gast03 automatically) would do the trick.